# Should I auto remove these packages?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

When I run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it outputs the following at the end:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.2.0-16 linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

Can I autoremove this?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.2.0-16 linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 287 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, feel free. Those are absolutely not needed, you already have two kernels installed. One is the latest one, and the other is the one from which you upgraded (now, regarded as recovery kernel). The third is the one which was used as a recovery kernel before the upgrade. Use this command to remove the oldest kernel of the three, i.e, 4.2.0.16:

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

**EDIT:** Ubuntu flavour is not the concern. The concept is applicable for all.

Comment: Linux X555LN 4.2.0-18-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:25:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: No, only the one that is being shown by the command: sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: BTW which version of ubuntu are using?

Comment: Since, you have three kernels, i.e., 16, 17, 18, running sudo apt-get autoremove will only remove the oldest one

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/92yhesuc5/

I have Ubuntu MATE 15.10

Comment: @MatjažJerman - edited

Comment: What if I don't remove it??

Answer (score 1):

If it is not the current kernel that you are using you may remove it using `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

You can find the current kernel version using the following command:

```
uname -a
```

I generally keep at least 2-3 kernels on my machine in case I have to boot into another one if something goes wrong.

Comment: Linux X555LN 4.2.0-18-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:25:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: How do I even boot into another one?

Comment: It is safe to remove since you are using the 4.2.0-18 version and it is going to remove the 4.2.0.16 one

Comment: I have this kernels in recovery: http://postimg.org/image/92yhesuc5/

If I do autoremove will it remove this entries too?

Comment: You can boot into the other one, by selecting it in the grub menu when you boot into your computer. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: Now it says to remove version 17. Should I keep it?

Comment: @Matjaž It is save to remove it but it is better to keep at least 1 previous kernel version.